# When using elven accuracy, do you have to take the results of the reroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, combat, advantage-and-disadvantage

The Elven Accuracy feat says:

"Whenever you have advantage on an attack roll using Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma, you can reroll one of the dice once."

Assuming you meet the requirements for using the feat, are you obligated to take the result of the reroll? Or can you just choose from the results of the original rolls and the Elven Accuracy roll?

I am trying to figure out if there would ever be any reason NOT to make a reroll and use the feat.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Reroll means re-roll: You roll the die again, whatever old value it had is gone and the new value is the new value. If it meant "roll another die and pick whichever you want", it would say that, much like the Lucky feat. You're "obligated to take the result of the reroll" only in the sense that the new roll becomes one of the two values that your Advantage is considering.

So if you made an attack with advantage and rolled a 10 and a 14, you would (normally) select the 10 to reroll with your Elven Accuracy. Suppose you get a 16 — now you have a 16 and a 14, and your attack uses the 16.  If your reroll had been a 7, you'd have a 7 and a 14, and you'd use the 14, same as if you hadn't had Elven Accuracy at all. You aren't obligated to use the 7, but it does become one of the two values Advantage is choosing from.

Comment: You might compare with Halfling Lucky, which says you **must** use the new result.  As you say, must is not used here, because the player still has the choice of the other roll with advantage.

Comment: It could also be compared to the 'Great Weapon' fighting style, because if you roll a 1 or 2, you must use the new result, regardless if it is a 1 or 2.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Elven Accuracy doesn't require you to reroll one of the dice in the first place; it says you "can reroll", not that you must. Beyond that, your answer is correct.

Comment: And note that it's perfectly fine to shortcut Elven Accuracy by just rolling 3 dice and picking the highest. The result is the same.

Comment: @Jorn Provided you're in the normal case where you want your roll to be as high as possible, it's the same as rolling 3 and picking highest. In theory, you *could* choose your higher roll to discard and reroll, though why you would do that is unclear. Maybe if there were a reason you were trying to avoid dealing a critical hit, or avoid rolling an even number, or some other strange corner case.

Comment: A spear/javelin of backbiting has a curse with an effect that activates upon rolling a 1 on an attack roll with it. It bends/flies to hit you in the back and forces you to make an attack roll with advantage against your own AC. Since I would assume most people do not want to attack themselves, this would be one such corner case.

Comment: Sure, that's a good example. It's fine to shortcut by just rolling three dice, as long as you understand that it is a shortcut and not the actual mechanic -- just have to keep in mind that there's an option to do it the long way if you're in one of those weird cases.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the other answer, your re-roll overwrites the (one) die you re-rolled, but since you can pick the lower die to re-roll, there is never a reason not to do it - you will get at least the value the other die shows. Because of it, Elven Accuracy is commonly treated in practice as "roll 3, pick highest" as it's functionally the same*.

* There is one exception to this however - if, for some reason, you aim to miss (pun intended) while having advantage. In that case, you could re-roll the higher die, so it would no longer be the same as "roll 3, pick highest".

Comment: Usually if you aim to "miss" at doing something, you wouldn't need a roll at all. Or you'd roll for something else entirely, for instance to convince observers that you tried your best, while deliberately failing. But that might be a discussion worth a separate question.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to imagine a scenario where such a thing might come up - for example, someone magically forces you to attack your ally, but you are under no obligation to make that attack effective.

Comment: While this is theorically a correct scenario, this also is very much metagaming, which brings more issues to the table, such as whether or not you can "pull your punches" when compelled to attack an ally, or whether or not being better at hitting foes also makes you better at not hitting someone you attack.

Comment: The best kind of correct.

Comment: Best kind of correct is "technically correct", not "theoretically correct".

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, you would need a roll, but if you chose to fail it, nobody would care what you rolled.

Comment: If you aim to miss you would usually try to hit somewhere close to the non-target. This would probably also require a roll (potentially with a different DC) because it's not that different technically.

Comment: @ilkkachu It's not. You still have advantage, so you need to pick the higher of the dice after reroll

Comment: @matszwecja, ahm, right, I somehow thought it was a free pick of the two. It's not even "roll three, pick the middle one", since if you have e.g. 10,14, and reroll, you might get 10,19. Hmm.

Comment: @ilkkachu You might have confused with Lucky which does allow a free pick.

Answer (score 3):

> When using elven accuracy, do you have to take the results of the reroll?

Yeah, that's what reroll means.

> Assuming you meet the requirements for using the feat, are you obligated to take the result of the reroll? Or can you just choose from the results of the original rolls and the Elven Accuracy roll?

It's not a matter of obligation, it's just simply what reroll means. This is different from Advantage because in those circumstances you roll 2 dice and keep the highest result. A reroll means the roll replaces it.

However, it's important to note, although the feat text doesn't specify which die, it would clearly be beneficial to **reroll the lower of the two advantage rolls**, so your end result is the better of the higher advantage die and the re-roll. If you reroll the higher die, you lose that option and could potentially have an end result that is lower than the highest of the two advantage dice.

Any automated tool, like dndbeyond, roll20, or whatever that has an Elven Accuracy feature always implements it as the best of three 20-sided die rolls, which is what it is if you reroll the lower advantage die.

> I am trying to figure out if there would ever be any reason NOT to make a reroll and use the feat.

By definition, if you are using the feat, you are re-rolling. If the question were

> Is there any reason not to use the feat?

or

> Is there any reason to re-roll the higher roll?

Kind of scratching my head here, but I cannot think of a situation where you would decide to attack with advantage, but do not want to hit. That would be the only conceivable situation where you would not apply the benefit of your feat, or perhaps apply it to re-roll the higher roll in the hopes it would be lower. You could certainly gain information that might change your mind about whether an NPC is an enemy or not, but seems highly unlikely to occur after the choice to attack has been made, but before the outcome is determined.